# Arbitrary C callback wrappers in Swift

Tags: c, swift, callback, wrapper

I have a C library with a lot of callbacks in the form

```
void asynchronous_thing(..., void* userInfo, SOMECBTYPE cb)
```

I am writing unit tests for these in Swift/XCT, and am wondering what the best solution to pass vars into the closure that Xcode/Swift generates for me automatically (I am providing one answer but my Swift is sub-par, so chances are high there is a much more elegant way to do this).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have:

```
class CUserInfoClass<T> {
    let v: T
    init(_ v: T) {
        self.v = v
    }
    init(_ userInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
        self.v = CUserInfoCallback<T>(userInfo).v.v
    }
}

class CExpectation : CUserInfoClass<XCTestExpectation> {
    func fulfill() {
        self.v.fulfill()
    }
}

class CUserInfoCallback<T> {
    let v: CUserInfoClass<T>
    init(_ v: CUserInfoClass<T>) {
        self.v = v
    }
    init(_ userInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
        self.v = Unmanaged<CUserInfoClass<T>>.fromOpaque(userInfo).takeUnretainedValue()
    }
    func wrap() -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
        return UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self.v).toOpaque())
    }
}
```

I use this in the following manner:

```
    func testAsyncThingie() {
        let exp = CUserInfoCallback(CUserInfoClass(expectation(description: "Wait for async thingie")))
        DoAsyncThing(exp.wrap()) {
            (ui, err) in
            XCTAssertNil(err)
            CExpectation(ui!).fulfill()
        }
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)
    }
```

where `DoAsyncThing` is

```
void DoAsyncThing(void*, void (*)(void* userInfo, const char* error))
```